# How to move field in sale order to stock picking

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have a problem, I made two custom fields in

- Sale.order
- Stock.picking

How to do when the sale order is confirmed, the field in `stock.picking` also filled? and the data was picked up from the field at `sale.order` I've made before.

I'm using **odoo 10**

Thanks

Comment: Just add compute field check here : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, first, depend in your module of sale_stock, then, inherit the sales confirm button and search for the pickings associated:

```py
@api.multi
def action_confirm(self):
    result = super(SaleOrder, self).action_confirm()
    for order in self:
        order.picking_ids.write({'your_field_in_picking': order.your_field_in_sale})

    return result
```

Put it in a class that inherits from sale.order

Comment: but sir, Where is it field "picking_ids" ?
I did not find it on module sale or stock

Comment: it is in sale_stock